# Non-toxic paint to mark metal cutlery

Tags: kitchens, paint, dishwasher, metal

In my office, we have a lot of private cutlery brought from home. Over time it magically disappears so I have bought new sets several times. Is there a paint (preferably in a pen) that can be used to mark the cutlery that is non-toxic and will survive dishwashing (at least hand washing, optimally machine washing as well, but that would be a nice-to-have)?

Comment: Instead of paint might think about an engraver to mark cutlery.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: "distinctive unusal pattern". Tried that, didn't work. I am not even accusing someone in the office of stealing things. They are all very nice. It's just that people sometimes take the cutlery with them to wash them at home and then simply forget to bring them back. A little visual cue would probably help them to remind them to bring it back.

Comment: Don't keep it in any communal area. Keep it in your desk drawer or in your own bag.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more of a [lifehacks.se] than [diy.se].

Comment: Manual carbide scriber (a hard sharp point in a pen-like handle) can be had for less than $10. Perhaps even less than $5. This is sufficient to mark (scratch) metal - it's not a fancy machine to do mechanically perfect letters, unless your freehand lettering skills approach mechanical perfection, but it will leave a permanent mark, and you can write with one with some effort/practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues here - identification and misappropriation (to put it extremely kindly). For both of them, I look to [keeping kosher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashrut) as a guide.

#### Identification

In the kosher world, there is a general need to have separate utensils for meat, dairy and pareve (neither meat nor dairy), based on the rules prohibiting consumption of meat and dairy together. Typical color-coding is red for meat, blue for dairy and green or yellow for pareve.

At home, many people simply use distinctive styles of cutlery and serving utensils for each type, store them in different locations in the kitchen and in general keep track of things to avoid mistakes. (But the mistakes happen anyway - one of the most common categories of calls for Orthodox Rabbis is meat/dairy mixups.) In a commercial setting, markings are an absolute must because new employees will take a while to recognize particular items, commercial serving utensils are often very generic looking (how many ways can you make a stainless steel big ladle) and in a busy kitchen it is really easy to get things confused. Even at home, many people will mark some or all items simply to avoid confusion when there are guests.

There are [labels](https://amzn.to/3pfwSr3) available. Other methods include tape (electrical tape is conveniently available in multi-color packs, but other types of tape may be more durable), various types of paint, nail polish and permanent markers. Toxicity usually isn't that much of a concern - the marking is being done on the handle, not the part that touches food, and most paints/markers/etc. are pretty stable once they are completely dry. Be careful with tape, particularly in automatic dishwashers, because if it comes off it could clog a drain.

In general, bold color markings are a more obvious symbol than engraving (often not obvious) or particular styles (I have two meat cutlery sets that are extremely similar purchased years apart from different companies.)

#### Misappropriation

This is likely the bigger problem. In the Kosher world, if there is a plausible chance that a utensil was used with non-kosher food (especially if hot), food of the wrong type (meat vs. dairy, especially if hot) or used with a "sharp" food (e.g., raw onions) then a special Kashering process may be required, which can vary from trivial (boiling water) to hard (blowtorch) to impossible/impractical. Essentially, if a utensil leaves the Kosher premises (restaurant, catering hall, etc.) and is not under direct supervision or in a sealed container then it will often be deemed non-Kosher until processed appropriately.

In your case, the concern is simply preventing people from taking the wrong stuff and/or getting it back if they "borrow" it. Color-coding *plus signage* can work well - Alice = Red, Bob = Blue, Carol = Green, Dave = Yellow on a big sign in the office kitchen/breakroom can be quite effective. Unfortunately, once you get past 8 - 10 people this [really doesn't work well](https://www.crayola.com/faq/another-topic/what-is-the-difference-between-greenblue-and-bluegreen-crayon-colors/). Crayola can handle 64, most people can't.

Which brings me to the last idea: Anyone who cares about their stuff should wash it when done eating and keep it in a box in their office or cubicle. The only utensils kept in the shared area should be company-supplied (or employee donated) items.